# Why I can't change a variable's value inside an if-then statement?

Tags: java

I've been trying to learn more about Java recently, so I followed an online guide on how to build a game in Java. Everything worked fine, but I wanted to add on more so I could make it my own. It's been going OK so far, but I've recently reached a personal impasse. Here's the code so far, including what I've added on my own (my question is at the bottom):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class PongGame extends JComponent implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener {
    public static PongGame game = new PongGame();
    private int ballX = 400;
    private int ballY = 250;
    private int paddleX = 0;
    private int ballYSpeed = 2;
    private int ballXSpeed = 2;
    private static int time = 15;
    public static Timer t = new Timer(time, game);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pong Game by Ethan");
        window.add(game);
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        t.start();
        window.addMouseMotionListener(game);
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //draw the background
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        //draw the paddle
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(paddleX, 510, 150, 15);
        //draw the ball
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 25, 25);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ballX = ballX + ballXSpeed;
        ballY = ballY + ballYSpeed;
        if (ballX >= paddleX && ballX <= paddleX + 150 && ballY >= 485) {
            ballYSpeed = -2;
            lessTime();
        }
        if (ballX >=775) {
            ballXSpeed = -2;
        }
        if (ballX <= 0) {
            ballXSpeed = 2;
        }
        if (ballY <= 0) {
            ballYSpeed = 2;
        }
        if (ballY == 500) {
            PongGame.infoBox("GAME OVER","");
            t.stop();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        paddleX = e.getX() - 75;
        repaint();
    }
    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "Game Over" + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    public static void lessTime() {
        time--;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a variable in there called `time` near the top which is used by `Timer t` right below it, and a method named `lessTime` at the bottom which just removes 1 from the `time` variable when called. I have it set to call the `lessTime` method in the first if statement when the ball bounces off of the paddle to increase the speed of the game (I'm working towards a hit counter), but it doesn't seem to increase the speed at all.

I've tried using `--time;`, `time--;`, and `time = time - 1;` all inside the `lessTime` method and by themselves in the `if` statement, but none of them remove any amount from the `time` variable. Can someone explain why the `time` variable isn't affected by either the method or alone inside the `if` statement, and also how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You're confusing the modification of the value of the `time` variable with modification of the value contained in the `Timer`.  Changing one won't affect the other, because Java is a [pass by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is because Java is a "pass-by-value" language.  This means that when you pass your `int time` variable into the constructor you're using to instantiate your `Timer t` variable, you have actually passed in the value of `int time` (15), not the `int time`variable itself.  The result is that if you change the value of your `int time` variable by decrementing it (so that it's now 14), the value inside your `Timer t` variable is still 15.

The shortest solution I can think of to get around your impasse is to add a line of code to your `lessTime()` method, like so:

```
public static void lessTime() {
    time--;
    // set t to a new Timer with the new decremented time value.
    t = new Timer(time, game);
}
```

Comment: The `Timer` can also be modified after construction using `setDelay`.

Comment: Actually, it should be modified using `setDelay`. Otherwise you would need to `stop` it first and `start` the new one afterwards.

Comment: This did work, but like Andreas said I had to use t.stop(); and t.start(); before and after resetting the timer. I also tried using t.setDelay(); like you suggested, but any value inside the parentheses set the game to a different pace but wouldn't increase continually like stop and start did. Do you have any suggestions on how to use setDelay?